# Simulating the evolution of a wavepacket through a crystal lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, simulations, semiclassical

I am interested simulating the evolution of an electronic wave packet through a crystal lattice which does not exhibit perfect translational symmetry. Specifically, in the Hamiltonian below, the frequency of each site $\omega_n$ is not constant.

Suppose the lattice is specified by a certain tight-binding Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_n \omega_n a^\dagger_n a_n + t \sum_{<n>} a^\dagger_n a_{n+1} +\text{all nearest neighbor interactions} + \text{h.c}.
$$
We prepare a wavepacket, and for simplicity, we express the wavepacket in the fock basis of each lattice site
$$
| \psi \rangle = \sum_i |b_1\rangle |b_2\rangle \ldots |b_n\rangle.
$$
Thus, there are $b_1$ electrons in the $1$st lattice site. Of course, electrons are fermions and $b_1$ may be either $0$ or $1$.

Suppose we treat this problem purely quantum mechanically. Then we will need to prepare a vector of length $2^n$, which is computationally intractable for any significant $n$.

I am interested in physical techniques that may be employed to simplify this problem. Is it possible to attempt the problem in a semiclassical manner?

Comment: Our [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) actually disavowes computational questions. With your permission I will migrate this to the [new Scientific Computation beta site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Of course, you can ask about the *physics* here not withstanding  that you are planning a computational attack, but this seems to be a implementation question. Or have I mistaken your intent?

Comment: I am more interested in the physical techniques that can be used to simplify the problem and hence, make it computationally viable. As we know, quantum mechanical simulations on classical computers are often intractable as the computational steps required increase exponentially with the degrees of freedom in the system.

Comment: At the end of the day, I would like to numerically time-step through some differential equation. The question is _which_ differential equation do I solve!

Comment: Ah...thank you for the clarification. This certainly should remain here.

Comment: @flamearchon For the exact method, you either use eigenvalue or direct evolution, and you dont have the symmetry in the Hamiltonian. The other method should only be approximation. If you get the answer, please post here.

Comment: @hwlau I'm unsure how to employ the semiclassical approximation to model the dynamics of this system. Do you have any suggestions or any literature you could point me towards? Thanks.

Comment: @flamearchon No, I dont, that is why I ask you about that. If there is a translational symmetry, we can use $O(2^n/n)$ instead. Usually, I see people prefer (probably my bias) using exact numerical method (not this problem, in genereal I mean). For your problem, there might probably be approximation that I dont know.

Comment: If you really want to know the answer, I can start a small bounty on it.

Comment: @hwlau I'm simulating lattices with the number of sites of order $10^3$. A preparing a Hilbert space of order $O(2^n)$ is still too large.

Comment: @hwlau Ashcroft & Mermin has a chapter on semiclassical techniques. However, the equations presented deal with the evolution of a wavepacket under external fields, which is not exactly my problem. Perhaps it is possible to deal with varying $w_n$ as a defect using perturbation theory? A small bounty would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @flamearchon I am a bit interested to see whether there is more general technique that I can learn.

Comment: Have you thought of using numerical algorithms, such as [tDMRG](http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/quantumsimulations/_media/dmrg-online.pdf), [TEBD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-evolving_block_decimation) ?

Comment: @Tarek: would you consider to write a short answer describing the method and benefit?

Comment: @hwlau I am not an expert in either of them. For sufficiently small systems, direct evolution with a simple 4th order Runge Kutta algorithm is sufficient. This amounts to using a truncated Taylor expansion of the time evolution operator. The Hamiltonian is represented as a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use tight-binding Hamiltonian, it is reasonable to start not from semiclassical, but one-particle approximation. In that case, you have an amplitude (complex number) at each site, the state is complex vector of length $n$, Hamiltonian is $n\times n$ (sparse) matrix and the problem of time evolution and/or eigenstates (for one particle state) is solvable for relatively large lattices.

If you are interested in many particle physics, you may build a model on top of these oneparticle states. The details are dependent on what exactly you wish to compute.

Unfortunately, I do not know a reference with rigorous transfer from one formulation to another.

Comment: Yes, usually we dont want to get the exact wavefunction. I think the ground state energy is usually one want to compute. Do you have any idea how to do that with some approximation?